# How to perform heavy synchronous operations w/o blocking the UI?

Tags: c#

I have a class containing a Run() method which executes a heavy operation blocking the UI.
I have created several instances of that class and I need to execute the Run() synchronously w/o blocking the UI.
I have managed to do so using a BackgroundWorker but **I don’t like this solution** because of the “Application.DoEvents()” and because If I need to wait for the background worker to complete, there is no use using a BW. I should use a synchronous operation.
Any ideas what can I use instead?

```
class MyClass
{
    public void Run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<MyClass> lmc = new List<MyClass>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyClass m1 = new MyClass();
        MyClass m2 = new MyClass();

        lmc.Add(m1);
        lmc.Add(m2);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (MyClass item in lmc)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw.RunWorkerAsync(item);
            while (bw.IsBusy)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MyClass)e.Argument).Run();
        ((BackgroundWorker)sender).CancelAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, basically, you want a solution that isn't asynchronous tasks even though this is exactly the situation asynchronous tasks were made for?

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework 4.5? If so, then look into the new async/await keywords in C# 5.

Comment: this can be useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Comment: If you are using `Application.DoEvents` then there is probably [something wrong](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html) with what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "DoEvents" indeed is not a good approach.
I suggest using TPL tasks.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task t = new Task(() =>
    {
        lmc.ForEach(l => l.Run());
    });

    t.Start();

    t.ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        Invoke(new System.Action(UploadDone));
    });

}

private void UploadDone()
{
    Console.Write("Done");
}
```

The only way to release UI is release the Main thread. You must start a new thread.

BTW,  If the lmc tasks are not relay on each other you can also do [Parallel Foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Thanks,
Amir

Comment: This solution will still block the UI !!!